# Google Chrome HTML Garbage Text in Windows XP

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am currently programming a website. I have basic html code, like any normal website displaying some contact information.

```
<p class="con_p bold">Minister: Brad Davis</p>
<p class="con_p">Phone: 214-563-2244</p>
<p class="con_p">Email: brad.w.davis@gmail.com</p>
<div class="space20"></div>
<p class="con_p bold">Minister: Leslie Rowe</p>
<p class="con_p">Phone: 214-212-9789</p>
<p class="con_p">Email: leslierowe1@yahoo.com</p>
```

On my Windows 7 PC, Chrome, IE and Firefox all display as should.

[Normal http://resource.deyogroup.com/419/dentonchurchWorking.png](http://resource.deyogroup.com/419/dentonchurchWorking.png)

Notice the Phone and Email specifically.

But on a friend's Windows XP computer running Chrome, it gets displayed as,

[Garbage Text http://resource.deyogroup.com/419/dentonchurchNW.png](http://resource.deyogroup.com/419/dentonchurchNW.png)

Would anyone know why the difference? Especially since it is both in the chrome browser?

Comment: Font problems? Try a different font.

Comment: I'm using Arial. As far as I know that's one of the web safe fonts right?

Comment: Yes; all XP computers have Arial. At least in theory; you never know what might have happened. Have you tried different fonts yet?